# How Do I Update Gridview in Real Time

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Can someone suggest me some .net development code for Real time updates in gridview?

I have one gridview in my webform. If i upload file in fileupload to sqlserver, my gridview from another computer or another browser then my current browser will automatically refresh with the changes. I don't need click manuallly refresh button or F5 to see the changes in my gridview.

thanks.

Comment: use partial page post-back to trigger that particular part of your page.

Comment: or use signalR for real time update

Comment: or u can use server send event, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events , but this not supported by IE

Answer (score 0):

here is the some option you can use

1. use a timer of the client and periodically poll for changes
2. use WebSockets
3. use Server-Sent Events (Content-Type: text/event-stream) but this
   is not supported by IE
4. signalR

Comment: number four..i have look that tutorial http://sylvester-lee.blogspot.com/2014/03/aspnet-signalr.html
but,it can't work too..

Comment: "it can't work" means what ,show your code where did you stack

Comment: i make Startup class like in that website 
here is my NotificationHub.vb

Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Namespace SignalRChat
    Public Class NotificationHub
        Inherits Hub
        Public Sub Send(name As String, message As String)
            ' Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace

Comment: in my home.aspx
var NotificationHub = $.connection.NotificationHub;
        NotificationHub.client.refresh = function (stock) {
            $("#Gridview1").each(function (i) {
if ($(this)[0].id == stock.ID) {
$(this).attr('style', 'background-color: yellow;');
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 3000);
                }
            });
        };

in home.aspx.vb
Dim context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of NotificationHub)()
Dim aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(1000)
aTimer.Interval = 3000
aTimer.Enabled = True
context.Clients.All.refresh()

Comment: it not update my gridview in other browser..
i'm a beginner user signalR..so, i'm very confused..
i hope you can help me :)

Comment: @peter it is better to ask new question with the your code which well format.it is hard to read here

Comment: i'm sorry sakir :)
okay,i ask new question with my source code..
thanks sakir :)

Comment: sakir,may i know your email?
I think we can disscuss in email..
because i can post new question after 90 min..
thanks :)